# JS считать последнию введеную строку

Tags: javascript, textarea

Добрый день, помогите решить задачу, нужно сделать подобие соц опросника на сайте, сайт спрашивает, а юзер отвечает(нужно именно строковый вариант,никаких кнопок, других полей и тп), т.к я только сегодня начал работать с js и тп, то кучу сразу вопросов. Начал я делать с помощью textarea, вывожу текст, но вот как считать именно последний ? тобишь, можно вродь как считать так текст :

```
var tex=document.getElementById('tt').value;
```

но оно возьмет все. Вот, что я накодил :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Стили</title>

 </head>
 <body>

<div class="fixed-textarea"> <textarea name ="tt" id="tt" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;" > </textarea></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
var text = '>> Сколько лет земле ? \r\n >> '
var i=0;
function type(){

    i++;
    if( i <= text.length )
        document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = text.substr(0, i);

    setTimeout( type, 50 );
}

function one(){

    var k= Math.random();

var tex=document.getElementById('tt').value;
    setTimeout( type, 10 );
}

type();

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что в вашем понимании будет считаться окончанием очередной введенной строки? Нажатие кнопки "Enter"? Так отвечающий может после каждой буквы Enter нажимать или же по ошибке нажать эту клавишу. В общем, хоть вы только начали изучение JS, но всё-таки ищите более реальные способы для вашей задачки.

Comment: не проще инпутами стилизировать под textarea?

Comment: @Deonis "Нажатие кнопки "Enter" "  
да,    
"Так отвечающий может после каждой буквы Enter нажимать или же по ошибке нажать эту клавишу." 
забыл добавить, что нужно еще сравнивать ответ, и тогда ошибку выдадим ему,   
"ищите более реальные способы для вашей задачки"
можете подсказать ?,    


"не проще инпутами стилизировать под textarea?" 
можно по подробнее ? я вообще не вкурсе ) если я правильно понял, то не совсем красиво выглядеть будет и не удобно, хотя ... можете более подробно рассказать ?

Comment: О "красоте" и о всяких "плюшках", на препубертатной стадии изучения, вам как бы задумываться рановато - это моё личное мнение. Набросал вам [максимально простой код](https://jsfiddle.net/frb7qo49/), который, я надеюсь, поможет вам хоть немного продвинутся вперед в освоении JS.